# Splitting one column's text based on another column's in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have two columns in my dataframe, 'Subject' and 'Description'. I am trying to clean the Description column by splitting the data on the text from the Subject column, as it's contained in all rows of the Description.

Here's a snippet of the Subject Column:

```
Subject
1     Question about the program   
2  Technical issue with the site
```

And the Description Column:

```
Description \
1  An HTML only email was received and a rough conversion is below. 
Please refer to the Emails related list for the HTML contents of the 
message. Question about the program Hello Hello I was wondering if there 
is going to be a product review coming up soon?

2  An HTML only email was received and a rough conversion is below. 
Please refer to the Emails related list for the HTML contents of the 
message. Technical issue with the site Reviews I received emails stating 
that I need to rewrite two of my reviews
```

For example on row 1, I would like the split on 'Question about the program' in the 1st row of the Description Column and only capture the text after that string.

I have tried 
`df['Description'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Description'].split(x['Subject'], 1), axis=1)['Description']`
but am having no luck and getting the error "TypeError: ('must be str or None, not float')" on an index that doesn't contain the title within the description. How can I handle the rows that don't contain this exact text while still splitting the ones that do?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I have also tried the suggested response and am given this error. `IndexError: ('list index out of range', 'occurred at index 1')`

Comment: I've tried that but get this error: "AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 1')"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the strings in `df['Description']` with specific value in `Subject` and take the later portion after split.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['Description'].split(x['Subject'])[1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0     Hello Hello I was wondering if there is going...
1     Reviews I received emails stating that I need...
```

Comment: Ok I have tried that and now I'm getting an IndexError, what could that be for?
`IndexError: ('list index out of range', 'occurred at index 1')`

Comment: For which row, do you get the error? This tells me that for some of your data, the Description does not have the Subject as a subtring.

Comment: for all rows. it either throws list index out of range or list has no attr str both of which make zero sense given the context

Comment: @Garglesoap as you can see it worked for OP. :((